# How do I show Device Geolocation share location prompt only on specific pages?

Tags: location

I am working with the Device Geolocation module packed with Smart IP. I got all the functionality working great, but I would prefer if the prompt to share your location wasn't given on every page of the website. The location service is only needed on two pages of the site, so I was wondering if there's any way to only load the Device Geolocation service on those pages, or somehow limit it to only ask to share location on one page and remember that (independent of browser settings).

Answer (score 1):

In the smart ip setting pages there is a setting to limit asking on specific pages.

Ask user's geolocation on specific Drupal native pages

Specify pages by using their paths (not the aliased path). Enter one path per line. The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are blog for the blog page and blog/* for every personal blog.  is the front page. Leave blank if all pages.

Comment: I had looked in the Smart IP settings before I enabled Device Geolocation, and everywhere for Device Geolocation settings, but not Smart IP after Device Geolocation was enabled. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much.